# How to run test by passing parameters with maven command in shell

Tags: java, shell, maven

-------------------- Test that needs to be run----------------

```
@org.testng.annotations.Test(groups = { "Regression" },parameters = {"environment"})

  public void As_a_User_I_can_Login_to_System(String environment){

       Users user = new Users("SID_SMITH");

      String name = loginHandler.success_login(user);

      System.out.print("Environment" + environment);

      Assert.assertEquals(name, user.getUserFullName(), "Success");

  }
```

I want to run above test by passing variable environment as input from shell script. Kindly give a guidance

Comment: Note that `parameters` is deprecated and you should use [`@Parameters`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-g317a92d-133/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your test from shell using following command

```html
mvn clean test -Dtest={testName} -Dgroups={groupName} -Denv={envname}
```

You can run multiple test by specifying test name separated by comma

```html
mvn clean test -Dtest={test1},{test2}
```